# Sphinx includes 'code' library descriptions where it's not supposed to

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I'm working on a documentation of an Python wrapper around a PyObjC application with Sphinx.

Sphinx adds a confusing and unwanted library description of the library *code* to this class's property description that happens to be *code* (please see screenshot, second last line).

How to get rid of it? I looked into conf.py, but couldn't find anything.
Also, I learned, **autodoc** adds more docstring stuff, but I never asked for it and and can't find whether this is what's even happening and how to turn it off.

The corresponding sphinx code is simply this:

```
Properties

.. autosummary::

    name
    code
    automatic
```

[image: Screenshot of HTML output]

Comment: What is your master_doc? Can you post the content?

Comment: Yes. It's [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5752966/Temporary/index.rst)